# Android bottom toolbar like snapped

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, material-design, toolbar

I am looking for something like toolbar for image editing app.
Is there a standard UI component or third party library which implements toolbar like [snapseed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed) app from Google?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a PopupWindow to achieve , take a look at : https://github.com/spyhunter99/supertooltip

Answer (score 0):

I think you can design this layout by yourself too.

Here are the steps you can perform:

1) Take a LinearLayout in your XML file and set its android:layout_gravity to bottom and set the orientation to horizaontal.

2)  Then take 5 ImageViews in it as child elements.

3) Set common properties of each Imageview and set android:layour_weight="1" to each ImageView.

4) Now In your java file findViewById all the ImageViews.

5) Now make a click listener for all of the ImageViews according to its functionality.

6) You can make visible or gone layouts on those click listeners as and when user click the menu items or your ImageViews(mainly those 3 icons in the middle)

7) Now on imageview clicks, you can make visible layout of that menu and give open/close animations accordigly.

Comment: Sure. But I am trying to find the easier way to do that rather than write the UI and animations on my own :-)

Comment: No Problem...Sergey